# global var out out init.go in revel

Tags: mysql, go, revel

(EDITING to fix capitalization and add context)

In revel's init.go, I have a global var: DB.

```
package app

import (
 "database/sql"
 "fmt"

 _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
 "github.com/revel/revel"
)
var DB *sql.DB

func InitDB() {

 connstring := fmt.Sprintf("revel:revel@tcp(localhost:3336)/revel")

 var err error
 DB, err = sql.Open("mysql", connstring)
 if err != nil {
    revel.INFO.Println("DB Error", err)
 }

}
```

How do I get that db variable in the rest of the app? Specifically, I was going to use this var in the models.

To start, how would I get it to work in this controller?
controllers/app.go

```
package controller

func (c App) Index() revel.Result {
 rows, err := app.DB.Exec("SELECT * FROM test_table")
 //do something with rows
 return c.Render()
}
```

Comment: Is that in `package main` or a library?

Comment: It's in package app (init.go file). I'm trying to access is, anywhere else.

Comment: In the same package just call db.Query (or another method. If you need to access it from another package, you need to export it as `DB`. Lowercase variables are private.

Comment: I just edited to fix capitalization and add a function I'd want to access DB in.

Comment: Have you tried it? If DB is global and within the same package, your Index() method should work.

Comment: I've tried it.
The Go code test/app/controllers/app.go does not compile: undefined: DB in DB.Exec

It doesn't work

Comment: Which package is `Index()` in? It doesn't sound like the same package as `InitDB()`, which you've said is in `package app`.

Comment: Index() is in package controller.

Answer (score 1):

Revel makes you "roll your own db" so it's up to you where connections are made and how to implement them.

Your `InitDB()` function must setup a ***public*** variable, e.g. `DB` (meaning its name is capitalized) which you will then access via the package that it lives in.

So notice your `app/init.go` is inside of `package app`:

```
package app

var DB *sql.DB

func InitDB() { DB = .... }
```

In Go, when your application is running each package acts as a sort of "singleton" so that anywhere else in the application where you access:

```
app.DB
```

This will look for the variable called `DB` in the `app` package. And if you have already run `InitDB()` to connect to the database, then `app.DB` will allow all other packages to use the database.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand. Booking does not initiate the DB in the init.go file.

Comment: Hiya  @Chemdream I have updated the answer to be very specific to your case. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for you help. It's still not working for me. I'm now getting: : undefined: app in app.DB ...

I've updated the code above as well to include my package declaration. Thanks!